# User kernel module "not found in directory"?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, linux-kernel-headers

I did a simple Linux kernel module. I can install the module temporarily via `sudo insmod my_module.ko` and use it.

But I tried and failed to load the module at boot time:

- copied it to `/lib/modules/5.4.0-1056-raspi/kernel/drivers/my_module/my_module.ko` (`uname -r` gives
  `5.4.0-1056-raspi`)
- added `my_module` line to `/etc/modules`
- rebooted

However, the module is not loaded: `Module my_module not found in directory /lib/modules/5.4.0-1056-raspi`.

But the module is there in the `kernel/drivers/my_module/my_module.ko` file!

`lsmod` does not list it.

Have in mind that this module worked perfectly before on the same machine, but the kernel at that point was `5.4.0-1047-raspi` and now I see it is `5.4.0-1056-raspi`, so I went on to install it again - but this time it doesn't work.

What could be done wrong?

p.s.
When I tried to compile `my_module.c` on this newer kernel, I got the error about missing license, so I added the line `MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");`  to the c file - than it compiled fine. That's the only difference in the source.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I needed to run `sudo depmod` first to re-generate the module dependencies, than `sudo modprobe my_module` to make it all work again.